# Where is my Django project on an Azure Web App

Tags: django, azure-web-app-service

I've successfully deployed a Django app on Azure. For the time being, it's based on SQLLite, but I plan to migrate to MySQL or PostgreSQL.
I connected to the Kudu console to locate my project folder. But I cannot see it. I would need that to access manage.py and launch some makemigrations, migrate and createuser for my  database server to come.
Is that due to the fact I am using a basic (and free) susbscription? Any other hint?

Any help is welcome

Richard

Comment: Have you deployed your app to Azure Linux app service?

Comment: Your subscription type is not the reason.The deployed app will be available for all types of subscriptions.

Comment: If the app is deployed in Linux environment then you can check the files at the new ui ..Open kudu console and redirect to `/newui`.URL will be  `Yourappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deployed the Django app to Azure App service using the basic plan and Azure Free Subscription and able to see the deployed files.

> Is that due to the fact I am using a basic (and free) susbscription?

The deployed app will be available for all types of Subscriptions and plans. There will be no change in checking the deployed files based on the plan and Subscription type.

Location differs only based on the Azure App Service Environment (Linux/Windows).

> I connected to the Kudu console to locate my project folder. But I cannot see it.

***Deployed files for Azure Linux App Service.***

The KUDU Console for Linux will have `SSH` and `Bash`.

To see the deployed files, run `ls` command in `SSH` or `Bash`.

***SSH:***

[image]

***NewUI for Linux:***

URL to open KuduLite - https://YourAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui

Navigate to `FileManager` => `site` => `wwwroot`, the files will be available as zipped `output.tar.gz`.

Download the `output.tar.gz` and extract the files.Now you can see the folder structure of all the deployed files.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, However, how could I run manage.py (makemigrations for instance or anything else) on the server if I have to download the folder ?

Comment: Run the command in the ssh itself.

Comment: Refer this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/django-app-model-python-manage-py-makemigrations-command/) once.